# Transferring from Parse-Server to dynamoDB. What foreseeable obstacles are there?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

As we all know, I'm one of the thousands of devs who relied on Parse and now forced to find Parse alternative. While transferring Parse-Server to AWS+MongoDB, I've discovered DynamoDB. I'm thinking of just tranferring my whole server side logic to DynamoDB. What are some of the problems that Parse doesn't have that might exist for DynamoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Parse includes a web server, you can interact with it via simple HTTP requests. DynamoDB is just a database, so you would need to connect directly through the AWS SDK, or build an API in front of it, possibly using API Gateway and Lambda.

In addition, since Parse is a full-featured Backend as a Service, and DynamoDB is only a database, there are some features in Parse that won't be available if you just use DynamoDB directly from your iOS application. For example user password resets require sending an email to the user. DynamoDB has no "password reset" functionality and can't send emails directly. You would have to build that feature yourself using something like Lambda and SES.

Parse also handles file upload and file hosting, which are features you would no longer have if you just used DynamoDB directly from iOS. You would have to build those features yourself, possibly using S3.

If you are only using Parse as a data store then using DynamoDB directly could certainly work for you, but then again so could MongoDB or any other NoSQL database. You should definitely explore how your database schema would look in DynamoDB before committing to it, because there are certain restrictions on index types and query types that might make it difficult to transition your current schema.

Comment: Sir, my hats off to you. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AWS + DynamoDB would be your way to go.

I worked extensively in both, DynamoDB and MongoDB systems and can give you a short summary of an advise.

MongoDB is very easy to work with and has unmatched flexibility in query structure, requires very little thinking ahead of setting up the system.

DynamoDB will provide unmatched scalability, much stricter (very strict) set of rules for creating schemas and requires a lot of planning before you do the setup. However, you don't need to worry about setting up or managing database environment, no worry about master/slave architecture and no concerns of scaling your database.

I go with DynamoDB these days and it's been great.

Comment: This is just a comparison of MongoDB vs DynamoDB without addressing the larger issues of transitioning from the Parse BaaS.

Answer (score 1):

Just completed a migration from Parse to AWS Dynamo (a few thoughts were posted here:  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/parse-aws-migration-server-less-mobile-backend-mike-kirkwood?trk=prof-post

My experience was that DynamoDD was an acceptable replacement for much of Parse.  However, it required some data model changes as DynamoDB doesn't support Pointers or Relationships like Parse did.   So, in the app had to adjust some of the writes to add more data to the record in DynamoDB.   This did offer some nice benefits in the queries.

DynamoDB also allows you to add indexes to match specific queries.

And, for my use, DynamoDB has proven to be much faster queries than Parse was.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I've also made the transfer and it seems like Dynamo is indeed faster and the learning curve is steep. I appreciate the link as well.

Comment: Sir, i read your very informative link and was wondering what the cost comparison between the two is if you don't mine me asking. Thank you

Comment: Good question!  Am doing a bit of analysis on this, will report back.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is just a database service, so you can use it to store Parse data but you'll still need a server to process the data and host APIs, etc... On AWS, you could spin up an EC2 instance to run the server, or try to make it run on Lambda.

Parse Server does not natively support either Lambda as a hosting environment or DynamoDB as a storage backend, but fortunately members of the community have recently developed integration for both of these:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-dynamodb-adapter
- https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/483